# Como pegar dados json vindo de php com javascript

Tags: php, ajax

Eu estou com uma duvida, como resgatar os valores, que são transformados em json, no javascript? Creio eu, que seja uma forma mais elegante de comunicar ambos. Ando vendo muita gambiarra na internet.

```
$json_data = array(
    "dados" =>  $Partner->listaParceiro($id) , 
);
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Basicamente, eu só gero um json com o php. Como eu consigo pegar esses dados com o javascript/ajax?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/send-data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache:false,
    success: function(data)
    {

    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Erro ao carregar');
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Acima basicamente o ajax que venho tentando

Erro gerado: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…)

**Conteudo da minha página**

Preciso pegar o select do "listaParceiro" e enviar para outra página. Ai pensei em gerar um json e recuperar esse json com javascript

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("classes/Partner.php");
require_once("classes/Clicks.php");
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $Partner = new Partner();
    $Cliques = new clicks();


    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $dataRegistro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $Cliques->setDataRegistro($dataRegistro);
    $Cliques->setIdPartner($id);

    $Partner->updateContCliques($id);
    //$Partner->listaParceiro($id);
    $json_data = array(
        "dados" =>  $Partner->listaParceiro($id) ,   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw.
    );
    echo json_encode($json_data);


    $Cliques->inserir();


}
else{
    header("Location: reg-partner.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>



    <?php
    require_once("cabecalho.php");
    ?>
</head>
</html>
<body>
<!-- /. WRAPPER  -->
<!-- SCRIPTS -AT THE BOTOM TO REDUCE THE LOAD TIME-->
<!-- JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- METISMENU SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/send-data.php?id=2', null, function (data) {
        alert(data.results); // Resultado: "Av. 7 de Setembro, S/N"
    })
/*
    var myUrl = encodeURIComponent("http://ecoprintq.com/index.php/partnerApplication/create");
    var dados = "User_full_name:aaaaaaa&User_institution:sssss"
    $.ajax({
        url: "webproxy.php?url=" + myUrl,
        data: dados,
        crossDomain:true,
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 30000,
        dataType: "text", // "xml", "json"

        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = "webproxy.php?url=" + myUrl + "&" + dados;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
            alert(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });*/


    var conteudoJSON;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/send-data.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            conteudoJSON = data;
            console.log(coneudoJSON);
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Erro ao carregar');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
</script>


</body>
```

================= Editando o post ============================

Com o que tu falou, é o json que veio... não é o json que eu esperava

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

================ 2 EDIÇÃO =========================

Meu code atual

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("classes/Partner.php");
require_once("classes/Clicks.php");
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $Partner = new Partner();
    $Cliques = new clicks();


    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $dataRegistro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $Cliques->setDataRegistro($dataRegistro);
    $Cliques->setIdPartner($id);

    $Partner->updateContCliques($id);
    //$Partner->listaParceiro($id);
    $json_data = array(
        "dados" =>  $Partner->listaParceiro($id)   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw.
    );
    echo json_encode($json_data);


    $Cliques->inserir();


}
else{
header("Location: reg-partner.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>


    <?php
    require_once("cabecalho.php");
    ?>
</head>

<body>
<!-- /. WRAPPER  -->
<!-- SCRIPTS -AT THE BOTOM TO REDUCE THE LOAD TIME-->
<!-- JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- METISMENU SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">




    var myUrl = window.location;
    .ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: myUrl
        data: {id:confirm("Insira o id desejado:")},
        //dataType: 'json',
        //contentType: 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Erro ao carregar');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
</script>


</body>
<?php

}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Se no sucesso da função colocar, `console.log(data);` aparece alguma coisa na consola?

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de mensurar o erro, editei no post

Comment: E não aparece nada

Comment: E tens a certeza que está alguma coisa a ser retornado do server (`echo json_encode($json_data);`) faz o que é suposto?

Comment: Sim, com certeza

Answer (score 0):

```
var conteudoJSON;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/send-data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache:false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        conteudoJSON = data;
        console.log(coneudoJSON);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Erro ao carregar');
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
//Ou trabalhe com seu  JSON da maneira que vc quiser usando esta variável.
```

Logo após o succcess, caso você não utilize ou especifique algo com o retorno data, ele se perderá e você não conseguirá a utilizar mais.

Caso você utilize o JSON internamente, há também a possiblidade de trabalhar com este JSON usando Data.atributo diretamente dentro do success.

Pode ser somente um caso de interpretação também, tente a seguinte alteração na sua página

```
else{
    header("Location: reg-partner.php");
//}
?>
```

//... manter o mesmo até

```
</body>
<? 
} ?>
```

Agora entendendo o que você quer, parece que você não está enviando o ID que você quer pegar do JSON, altere para o seguinte:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/send-data.php",
    data: {id:confirm("Insira o id desejado:")},
    .....
```

Se sua intenção for passar todos os elementos do seu objeto, você precisaria enviar uma variável TODOS e testá-la do lado do PHP, através de um $Partner->listaTodosParceiros() por exemplo

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54193/discussion-on-answer-by-jefissu-como-pegar-dados-json-vindo-de-php-com-javascrip)

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/send-data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache:false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj.atributoJSON);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Erro ao carregar');
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

`obj` vai ser seu objeto json e atributoJSON é um atributo desse objeto. Se você retornar do PHP um JSON que seja Aluno com nome, por exemplo, você pode acessar isso através de `obj.nome`